# Weird unexpected image compression on a web server running Apache on Ubuntu?

Tags: apache2, ubuntu, compression, images

I have a weird problem on my production web server running Apache on Ubuntu: it compresses my images thereby dramatically lowering their quality!

Actually I have two virtual hosts running, each located in a different folder. Wether I display .gif images by navigating on the two sites, or acceding them directly by their url, their size and quality are invariably degraded.

I tried with three different browsers: same problem. Using them on other sites on the Web: no problem. Of course I disabled mod_deflate on the server (which should not compress images anyway), but the phenomenon remains.

On my local développement server, running the same configuration, everything is Ok.

Now I'm completely lost!

For the record, my configuration: Ubuntu 10.04, Apache 2, Php 5.

Answer (score 2):

This might be [mod_pagespeed](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/), which has [filters to "optimize" images](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/filter-image-optimize.html).

Unfortunately without posting your Apache configuration, it's impossible to tell. You might find `apache2ctl -t -D DUMP_MODULES` useful to list the modules currently loaded into your web server.

Comment: mod_pagespeed is not loaded according to apache2ctl.

Answer (score 0):

In Apache, the Content Negotiation can be finely configured for different media types.  For Image types such as `image/jpeg`, `image/gif` etc, there's an option to serve them at different qualities.

With any luck you may have some directives that look like this:
`Accept: image/gif, image/jpeg; q=0.40` in your httpd.conf/apache.conf

For more info, see the [Content Negotiation section in the Apache Documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/content-negotiation.html#better).

Comment: Thanks. No, there is no such thing in the apache conf file(s).